# Kadane's Algorithm

Tags: python

> Given an array of positive integers nums, return the maximum possible sum of an ascending subarray in nums.
>
> A subarray is defined as a contiguous sequence of numbers in an array.
>
> A subarray [numsl, numsl+1, ..., numsr-1, numsr] is ascending if for all i where l <= i < r, numsi < numsi+1. Note that a subarray of size 1 is ascending.
>
> Input: nums = [10,20,30,5,10,50]
>
> Output: 65
>
> Explanation: [5,10,50] is the ascending subarray with the maximum sum of 65.

Hi guys, I found this problem on leetcode and i dont understand why it start at 5 and ends at 50. I am trying to do this with Kadane's Algorithm. If I do this with Kadane's Algorithm my Array looks like that:

[10,30,60,65,75,125] <----- why do they pic the last 3 elements? The Sum is bigger if they pic more Elements, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question; **ascending subarray**.
[10,20,30,5,10,50] is not ascending, it breaks at 30, 5.

Either pick [10,20,30] or [5,10,50] and then next condition comes into picture, you need to get maximum and hence [5,10,50] is the answer.